# AngularJS and image resizing

Tags: angularjs

I used to have this .net MVC website that used server side logic to resize images based on the browser width. It didn't just load a large image and scale it down, it actually took the image and created a new image which it served to the client.
It was small and the impact on mobile browsers was minimal.

Now I have just built a large application using AngularJs. In this application I decided to create my own images and serve them using a ImageService which looks a bit like this:

```
.service('ImageService', ['$window', '$q', 'PreloaderService', function ($window, $q, preloader) {

    // Create our variables
    this.loading = true;
    this.successful = false;
    this.percentLoaded = 0;

    // Function to search for images using the current window width
    this.search = function (fileNames) {

        // Create an array
        var array = [];

        // Get our directory 
        var directory = this.getBackgroundImageDirectory();

        // Loop through our images
        for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {

            // Get our current file
            var fileName = fileNames[i];

            // Get our image
            var image = directory + '/' + fileName;

            // push to our array
            array.push(image);
        }

        // Return our array
        return array;
    };

    // Function used to preload a set of images
    this.preload = function (fileNames) {

        // images
        var images = this.search(fileNames);

        // Create our promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Preload the images
        preloader.preloadImages(images).then(

            // Function to handle the changing of the flags when all images have loaded
            function handleResolve(imageLocations) {
                this.loading = false;
                this.successful = true;

                deferred.resolve(images);
            },

            // Function to handle any errors
            function handleReject(imageLocation) {
                this.loading = false;
                this.successful = false;

                deferred.reject();
            },

            // Function that notifies our percentage loaded flag
            function handleNotify(event) {
                this.percentLoaded = event.percent;
            }
        );

        // Return our promise
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.getBackgroundImageDirectory = function () {

        // Get the window width
        var width = $window.innerWidth;

        // Get the base directory
        var baseDir = '/assets/images';

        // If the width is greater than 1920px
        if (width > 1920) {

            // Select the retina directory
            return baseDir + '/retina';

            // Else, if our width is greater than 1200px
        } else if (width > 1200) {

            // Select the large directory
            return baseDir + '/lg';

            // Else, if our width is greater than 992px
        } else if (width > 992) {

            // Select the medium directory
            return baseDir + '/md';

            // Else, if our width is greater than 768px
        } else if (width > 768) {

            // Select the small directory
            return baseDir + '/sm';

            // Else, if our width is greater than 480px
        } else if (width > 480) {

            // Select the extra small directory
            return baseDir + '/xs';
        }

        // Catch all
        return baseDir + '/mobile';
    };
}])
```

The main method here is the **preload** function. When invoked it takes a list of filenames and invokes the **search** method, which in turn loops through the filenames and prepends the correct directory based on the browser width.
This actually works, albeit that there are numerous images.
Now it is coming to the point, where creating 8 different version of the same image is cumbersome and time consuming.
So I was wondering if there was a way to combine angularJS and and some server side logic to create and serve an image from a base image, similar to the example I gave above.

I could write a directive to get the source image and then using $http, call my server side function and return a new image that best fits the browser.

Before I start developing this, I have a couple of questions:

1. Has this been done before? if so, does anyone have any examples
2. Is this actually a good way to handle images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble with your approach, as you're finding out, you need a bunch of the same images and a whole other bunch of logic dictating which folder to look into for the image. The moment another device comes on board you're going to have to replicate a whole bunch of stuff.

I personally ask my server to provide me with an image to the site i require. So if i'm serving the image on a phone, for example, i would call a method that returns an image rendered to the size I want.

Much less logic.

You're used to ASP.Net MVC so I imagine Web API is what you're using for your API?

Something, psuedo, like this would do (I actually use this method sig)

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage ShowResizedImage([FromUri] string imagePath,     
        [FromUri] int longestSideSize, 
        [FromUri] bool longestIsWidth) {

        // Call your own services to perform your image manipulation

         // Then return your image stream    
         HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
         response.Content = new StreamContent(myImageMemoryStream);
         response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png"); // or whatever...    
}
```

You can then use this in your `img` like:

```
<img src="/api/imaging/showresizedimage?imagePath=yourimagepath&longestsidesize=120&longestIsWidth=true" />
```

You could just as easily, if you're not using Web API, is use an `*.ashx` handler to serve the image too.

Comment: Yeah, I had the code already, I was just wondering if this is a good way of doing it; your answer confirms it for me though. I was also wondering if saving the image to the server might also be a good idea. So if someone requests an image at mobile level I could save the image like **image_400.jpg** then the next time someone requests that same image, rather than regenerate it, it just loads it from the server. Not sure if this would be faster or not?

Comment: Cool. Saving it wouldn't be a bad idea especially if it's a really heavy-traffic site